# ASP.NET Core Higher memory use uploading files to Azure Blob Storage SDK using v12 compared to v11

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-5, azure-blob-storage

I am building a service with an endpoint that images and other files will be uploaded to, and I need to stream the file directly to Blob Storage. This service will handle hundreds of images per second, so I cannot buffer the images into memory before sending it to Blob Storage.

I was following the article [here](https://trailheadtechnology.com/dos-and-donts-for-streaming-file-uploads-to-azure-blob-storage-with-net-mvc/) and ran into this comment

> Next, using the latest version (v12) of the Azure Blob Storage libraries and a Stream upload method. Notice that it’s not much better than IFormFile! Although BlobStorageClient is the latest way to interact with blob storage, when I look at the memory snapshots of this operation it has internal buffers (at least, at the time of this writing) that cause it to not perform too well when used in this way.

> But, using almost identical code and the previous library version that uses CloudBlockBlob instead of BlobClient, we can see a much better memory performance. The same file uploads result in a small increase (due to resource consumption that eventually goes back down with garbage collection), but nothing near the ~600MB consumption like above

I tried this and found that yes, v11 has considerably less memory usage compared to v12! When I ran my tests with about a ~10MB file the memory, each new upload (after initial POST) jumped the memory usage 40MB, while v11 jumped only 20MB

I then tried a 100MB file. On v12 the memory seemed to use 100MB nearly instantly each request and slowly climbed after that, and was over 700MB after my second upload. Meanwhile v11 didn't really jump in memory, though it would still slowly climb in memory, and ended with around 430MB after the 2nd upload.

I tried experimenting with creating `BlobUploadOptions` properties `InitialTransferSize`, `MaximumConcurrency`, etc. but it only seemed to make it worse.

It seems unlikely that v12 would be straight up worse in performance than v11, so I am wondering what I could be missing or misunderstanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue may occur due to Azure blob storage (v12) libraries.

Try to upload the large files in chunks [a technique called file chunking which breaks the large file into smaller chunks for each upload] instead of uploading whole file. Please refer this [link](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-large-files-to-azure-blob-storage-in-c-sharp)

I tried  producing the scenario in my lab

```
public void uploadfile() 
        { 
            string connectionString = "connection string"; 
            string containerName = "fileuploaded"; 
            string blobName = "test"; 
            string filePath = "filepath"; 
           BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName); 
            container.CreateIfNotExists(); 
            // Get a reference to a blob named "sample-file" in a container named "sample-container" 
            BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName); 
            // Upload local file 
            blob.Upload(filePath); 
         }
```

The output after uploading file.

[image]